# getting different results when using Bing V5 API vs bing.com

Tags: bing, bing-api

So I am trying to implement Bing Search V5 API (click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7mpay26o/3/) for full code).

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search",
    data: {
      "q": $("#search-text").val() + "+site:berkeley.edu",
      "mkt": "en-US",
      "responseFilter": "Webpages",
      "count": "10",
      "offset": "0"
    },
    beforeSend: function(xhrObj) {
      xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "supply-your-own-key-here");
    },
    type: "GET",
  })
```

As a test, I searched using bing.com (click [here](http://www.bing.com/search?q=medicine%20site%3Aberkeley.edu&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=undefined&sc=9-26&sk=&cvid=38B04F7351B649008C04EAB7B459A077) for search results) and the first 10 results I'm getting is completely different from the results I'm getting using my code. I've added a screenshot that shows the search results.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong? Thanks

ps. I've found similar discussion but they were from 2011 and things most likely has changed since then.

screeshot of search results using my code:

[image: screeshot of search results using my code]

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything "wrong". It's simply that an extra setting is giving you a different result. The setting for *mkt=en-US*, causes the difference.

Not supplying it gives the same result, for instance in Postman.

Changing it  to use *cc* instead, "A 2-character country code of the country where the results come from." Results in the same as with the mkt.
So likely if you want Bing result, don't supply anything.